# How to add a % symbol on a Squarify treemap

Tags: python, percentage, squarify

I'm trying to plot a treemap with Squarify.
But i don't realize how could i add a "%" to a float value.

```
ListaCryptos = ['BTC', 'ETH']
tamaños2 = [61,755, 32,992]

sq.plot(sizes=np.around(tamaños2, decimals=2),
            label=ListaCryptos,
            value=np.around(tamaños2, decimals=2),
            color=colores,
            pad=True,
            alpha=0.9,
            bar_kwargs=dict(linewidth=2, edgecolor="white"),
            text_kwargs={'fontsize': 32})

    plt.title("Rentabilidad", fontsize=32, fontweight="bold")
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Then in the plot i need to the values express like
61,75%
32,99%

How could i add a percent symbol to my float values.

Comment: `[61,755, 32,992]` means 4 values: `61` and `755` and `32` and `992`. To have two values you have to use dots in `61.755` and `32.992`. And to display `%` you would have to convert to strings and add `%`

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `[61,755, 32,992]` means four values: `61` and `755` and `32` and `992`.
To have two values you have to use dot (`.`) in `61.755` and `32.992`

---

To display `%` you have to convert `float` to `string` and add `%`.

Using `f-string` you can create string with `%` and you can even round value.

```
value=[f'{x:.2f}%' for x in tamaños2],
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import squarify as sq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cryptos = ['BTC', 'ETH']   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
values = [61.755, 32.992]  # PEP8: English names for variables

sq.plot(sizes=np.around(values, decimals=2),
        label=cryptos,

        value=[f'{x:.2f}%' for x in values],  # <---

        #color=colores,
        pad=True,
        alpha=0.9,
        bar_kwargs=dict(linewidth=2, edgecolor="white"),
        text_kwargs={'fontsize': 32})

plt.title("Rentabilidad", fontsize=32, fontweight="bold")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)